# How can I stop exporting an empty .ear file?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ear

For my maven project, I can generate a functioning `.jar` via `mvn compile`.

However, after importing the project in Eclipse, the default `Export` action becomes to export an `.ear` file, which is always exported (and automatically built by higher-level projects) empty, with only the Manifest file, although I can still export manually to a functioning .jar.

How can I fix this, by either exporting a `.jar` or a class-and-stuff-containing `.ear`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [Maven EAR plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/).

Here is a [nice documentation](http://antoniogoncalves.org/2009/10/23/because-i-always-forget-how-to-use-maven-ear-plugin/) on how to use maven-ear-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your project's pom file specifies the compiled artifact type as a jar like so:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

If that is the case then look for a 'parent' project refference to another .pom which might be the one dictating how Eclipse is compiling the project.

eg.

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
  </parent>
```